# Eclipse and EGit: how to commit build directories

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, egit

I'm using Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) with CDT and EGit 2.0.0. I want to commit build directories (`Debug` and `Release`) because they contain `makefile`, so if I want to compile my project in a host without Eclipse, I can clone the repository, `cd` to the `Release` directory and call `make all`.

My `.gitignore` is this:

```
*.o
*.d
Debug/MyApplication
Release/MyApplication
```

If I call `git status` from a console, it tells that `Debug` and `Release` directories are untracked, so I can call `git add .`.

From Eclipse, this is impossible: it simply ignore Debug and Release directories.

So... how to force Eclipse to stage these directories? I don't want to call git from command line everytime makefile changes.

Comment: Did you tried it in the java-view or in the git-view? I can select all directories in the git-view.

Comment: Tried even in Java perspective, Package Explorer view, right click on project, `team -> commit", it tells that "No changed items were selected", even if Release directory is present in working directory, but not in repository. I can add it only via command line git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to EGit 2.1 with the following update site (or use the [nightly update site](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly)):

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

EGit used to ignore derived resources (e.g. Eclipse build output folders) before 2.1.

In 2.1, this was changed so that it is consistent with Git, see [bug 359052](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=359052). It now only ignores files that are explicitly excluded (e.g. by `.gitignore`).

Comment: This works, thanks. I was looking for some hidden configuration in eclipse preferences, but it was only an *EGit* bug.